# how to give strongly name to subsonic.core.dll

Tags: subsonic

Can you help me? I need to have subsonic.core.dll strongly named.
How can I do this?

Best Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to get the source and build it yourself (and sign it).